# About Unity Error : "SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to distribute the following code to users to receive UDP:

**UDPReceive.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public class UDPReceive : MonoBehaviour
{
    int LOCA_LPORT = 22222;
    static UdpClient udp;
    Thread thread;

    void Start ()
    {
        udp = new UdpClient(LOCA_LPORT);
        udp.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
        thread.Start(); 
    }

    void Update ()
    {
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        thread.Abort();
    }

    private static void ThreadMethod()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = null;
            byte[] data = udp.Receive(ref remoteEP);
            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
            Debug.Log(text);
        }
    } 
}
```

https://qiita.com/nenjiru/items/8fa8dfb27f55c0205651

However, if the user attaches this file to more than one object, an error is issued.

Error message is as follows.

```
"SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address"

System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind (System.Net.EndPoint local_end)
System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.InitSocket (System.Net.EndPoint localEP)
System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient..ctor (Int32 port)
UDPReceive.Start () (at Assets/UDPReceive.cs:16)
```

If "I" only use this file, it is no problem if I make sure I don't attach it to multiple objects.

However, when used by "other users", users may wonder why the error occurs.

So, when a user encounters this error, I want to give a message saying "This script must not attach to more than one object."

How can I do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **why** the error occurs is quite self-explanatory and I think you already got the problem: You can listen on one port only once. A second script would need to use another port.

---

How to avoid it and give a proper warning/error?

There are a lot of options.

- One might be e.g. to check how many are there in a scene using `FindObjectsOfType` like e.g.

  ```
  private void Awake()
  {
      var instances = FindObjectsOfType<UDPReceive>();

      if(instances.Length > 1)
      {
          Debug.LogError("Found multiple instances of UDPReceive! Only one is allowed!");
      }
  }
  ```

  this you could actually also already do in [`Reset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html) which is called as soon as the component is attached to an object. This way you could already show the error before PlayMode is even started!
- Another one would be a classical Singleton-Pattern

  ```
  // as this is static it is "shared" between all instances or
  // better said it is not bound to any instance at all
  private static UDPReceive instance;

  private void Awake()
  {
      // check if another instance already exists
      if(instance && instance != this)
      {
          Debug.LogError("There is already another instance of UDPReceive in the scene! Only one is allowed!", this);
          Debug.LogError("That's true, I am the active instance for this scene", instance);

          this.enabled = false;
          return;
      }

      // otherwise become the instance yourself
      instance = this;
  }
  ```
- You could also catch the exception and show your own custom message like e.g.

  ```
  void Start ()
  {
      try
      {
          udp = new UdpClient(LOCA_LPORT);
          udp.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
          thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
          thread.Start();
      }
      // If any SocketException is thrown while starting the UDP client
      // it is most probably due to the port already being in use
      catch(SocketException e)
      {
          Debug.LogError("UDP cliente has a SocketException." 
             + "/nThis is probably caused by the target port already being used by something else." 
             + "/nMake sure you have only one instance of UDPReceive in your scene and try again", this);
      } 
  }
  ```

---

As a side note: It actually **would** be possible to use this multiple times in the same scene by simply allowing the developer to choose a different port:

```
//                                | probably a typo btw ;)
//                                v 
[SerializeField] private int LOCA_LPORT = 22222;
```

This still uses `22222` as default but now someone could also use a custom one. (You should then ofcourse rename it to comply with the c# coding conventions)